# constants and inputs with Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a regex for a string I write down.

My string is like :

```
'AUR HALAA /PART="PROJECT" /ROLE="VR_ANALYST" /TYPE="C" /CAPABILITY="S" /ADD' (SUC)
```

The constant part in regex is :

```
'AUR 

/ROLE=""
```

The inputs are:

```
HALAA

VR_ANALYST
```

I tried the regex like this:

> \'(AUR) HALAA .* /ROLE="(.*)" .*

but it doesnt work.

Could you please show me some tricks to how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^AUR (\\w+).*?/ROLE="(\\w+)".*$
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex might work for you

```
^AUR (\\w+) .*? /ROLE="(\\w+)" .*$
```

And, you can then use "groups" in Matcher class to get the matching groups which will give you HALAA at group(1) and VR_ANALYST at group(2)

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I have two questions. First, whats the meaning of w+, could you please explain groups more detaily. I think I cannot understand fully.

Comment: \w+ matches one or more word characters. With groups you can "catch" a part of the input and reference or access it later. For more information about regular expressions you should have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/ or read in the Java docs for the class java.util.regex.Pattern.